# gdb command to check the variable exist

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, command

In GDB Scripting, how can I check if a stack variable exists?

I've GDB script to walk through stack and access variables (on stack). 
But if the variable does not exist the script exits with the following error:

```
< No symbol "variable" in current context >
```

I was wondering if there is a gdb command to check if the variable exists?  Is there a way to catch these exceptions and exit cleanly?

Comment: For convenience vars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744554/testing-if-a-gdb-convenience-variable-is-defined

Answer (score 2):

By far the simplest way to do this is to script gdb using Python.  Python has been available for years now.

However, maybe it can be done in the ordinary gdb command language.  It's not very scriptable but sometimes things can be done with tricks.

Since you're only looking at stack variables, I'd suggest redirecting the output of "info args" and "info locals" to a file.  Then shell out to a script to rewrite this list into a new list of commands.  By shelling out you can also easily filter out the not-found variables.  Then, have gdb "source" this new list of commands to do whatever you like.

Let me reiterate, though, that this is 1000x simpler from Python.  You can even take the quick-and-dirty approach and find the Python "ignore-errors" script -- this will let your script ignore errors from gdb commands.

Comment: Thx for response. I see python command in gdb but don't see how I can run a python py file in it. Only allows running simple commands. But for to achieve walking stack I'll need a full fledged script.

Comment: looks like I can run python script thru source command  : 'source -s pythoncode.py'